# Chrome Dev Tools: what does <symbol> mean in heap profile?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory, heap-dump

I was recently looking through a JavaScrip heap profile in Chrome Dev Tools, and came across an interesting entry:

[image: screenshot]

`NoAgentIdError` is an exception class with stack trace capture enabled:

```
var NoAgentIdError = function(entity) {
  Error.call(this);
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, arguments.callee); // jshint ignore: line
  this.message = 'No agent ID defined for entity: ' + entity;
};
util.inherits(NoAgentIdError, Error);
```

So the question is: what is `<symbol>`, why is `NoAgentIdError` holding it and why does it consume 3% of total heap?

Answer (score 0):

Symbol is a new type in the new ES6 Javascript standard. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol